# In Ektron, Load Last Active Location

Tags: ektron

**Question:** 
Anyone know what setting in my user profile will make Ektron always load the last active work area location? If not, is there a way to load a specific folder every time?

**Already Tried:**
"Set smart desktop as the start location in the workarea." doesn't seem to do anything.

**Why:**
I'm primarily a designer, so I'm usually just replacing files in the library and leaving the content area to the developers. It's kind of annoying that the content area always loads first because the folder structure looks the same and many times I actually navigate to the content folder instead of the library folder. This is a waste of time because Ektron is so slow. It would be really helpful to load the last active location in the area or at least the library files first.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no. At least, not in any way that would be supported by Ektron or be upgrade-safe (upgrades would likely destroy changes made to include this functionality).

The long answer is that the Workarea code source is available and a .NET developer who wanted to parse through it and figure it out would probably be able to do so. It would require adding a user property / cookie to store their last activity (at the desired level of specificity) and then update any and all related code files that would automatically take them to any given recorded location. It would be inadvisable due to the effort required and for the upgrade-related reasoning above.

THAT BEING SAID - Ektron's Workarea uses Frames and you ***may*** be able to bookmark one of those internal frames or else create your own set of frames in your own HTML that would load up the view that you want. Depends on whether it's important enough to you to put in the effort to figure those things out by inspecting enough of the client-side code.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'm just a user not an admin, so yeah it's probably not worth it to go through all of that just to avoid some extra clicks and load time  just for my profile.